# Prove that $n^2+11n+2$ is not divisible by $12769$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

My  Attempt :

Prime factorisation of $12769$ is $113^2$

$n^2+11n+2-113^2m=0$

The conjugate of this quadratic equation becomes:

$\sqrt {113 (113m+1)} $

which can never be a rational as (113,113m+1)=1 and 113 is not a perfect square (and its prime )

I belive this method is right,but I am asking for a modular method of doing this, which I believe will be easier. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$113$ is prime.

$$n^2+11n+2\equiv 0\pmod{113^2}$$

$$\stackrel{\cdot 4}\iff (2n+11)^2\equiv 113\pmod{113^2}$$

$$\implies 113\mid (2n+11)^2\iff 113\mid 2n+11$$

$$\iff 113^2\mid (2n+11)^2$$

$$\iff (2n+11)^2\equiv 0\not\equiv 113\pmod{113^2}$$

Comment: I don't get the last step. Why did you show 113 will not be a remainder?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN The first equivalence shows that $(2n+11)^2\equiv 113\pmod{113^2}$ while the last equivalence shows that $(2n+11)^2\equiv 0\pmod{113^2}$. These two statements contradict each other.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Will accept in 4 mins

Comment: Yes I know. That's how the quadratic solutions formula is derived

Comment: @N.S.JOHN It's useful to know that you can always multiply both sides of a quadratic congruence by $4a$ to complete the square: If $\gcd(n,2a)=1$, then $$ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{n}$$

$$\iff (2ax+b)^2\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{n}$$

If $\gcd(n,2a)\neq 1$, then use $\implies$ instead of $\iff$.